# Executing the same workflow on a list of items (possibly in a file) using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a file with say a list of items (Kernels) which keeps changing everyday and I would like to setup Jenkins to do the following:

1. Setup Jenkins to read the file ( it could have anywhere between 10 - 200 line)
2. execute a workflow ( boot, make some changes, reboot) on each of those items
3. Finally I'd like to do all this in parallel so that I can debug the ones that failed this process

I don't know how to use the pipeline plugin to get this going. Any help will be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use groovy to iterate along the file : [Reading File with Groovy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_file_io.htm)
2. Use a keyword to launch specific work (Groovy switch for example)
3. Look job function to launch other Jenkins Job in parallel : [Build Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)

Please try it on your own and update your question with what you've done if needed. It is a good help for readers to give example of what you've done so far.